# VueJs - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'modules[moduleId].call')

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, web, webpack

VueJS

Getting this error whenever I try accessing a page that was modified.
This error only happens on production.
When serving locally it doesnt occur.

It usually gets fixed when a new build gets triggered.

What could be the problem?